# Calculate the time gone and left while playing an audio file

Tags: android, audio, media-player, duration

How can I find out the time (second) that **my** `MediaPlayer` played the music in `ms`

I want to segment a single audio file to determinate durations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getCurrentDuration() method of MediaPlayer. Refer [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592445/2003486) on here and also a good solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885629/2003486).